# Thunderbird 5 not deleting messages older than X when using POP3

Tags: thunderbird

I've been using my sites webmail (Squirrelmail) only for a few months due to a disk crash on my desktop that hosed my Thunderbird.

With the desktop up and running again, I installed Thunderbird 5 and created a POP3 account. I set it to "Leave Messages on Server" "For at most 91 days"

After doing a pop3 run, it downloaded the messages, but left all of the messages, even the messages older than 91 days on the server.

Any idea what I need to look at?

Comment: Have you done another download since then on another day?

Comment: yes, this morning and the older that 91 days messages are still on the server.